# Laravel 5 advance routing with reserved route keywords

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Would like to check say that I have the following routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/{profile_url?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile'));
    Route::get('/settings/password', array('as' => 'chgPassword', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@updatePassword'));
    Route::post('/settings/password', array('as' => 'postChgPassword', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@postUpdatePassword'));
    Route::get('/settings/email/request', array('as' => 'chgEmailRequest', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@updateEmailRequest'));
    Route::post('/settings/email/request', array('as' => 'postChgEmailRequest', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@postUpdateEmailRequest'));
    Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@logout'));
});
```

Notice that my first route accepts an optional parameter which will then route the user to a specific profile which it works fine, but when ever i have other routes say that `/logout`, laravel router will also use the `/{profile_url?}` route instead of the expected logout route. Is there any way that i can specified something like a reserved keyword like

```
Route::get('/{profile_url?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile')
->except('settings', 'logout'));
```

something like that? Ho that someone can enlighten me with this issue.

Comment: Put the least specific route ({profile_url?}) at the last place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put a wildcard `{profile_url?}` at the first place, Laravel will ignore the rest. So be careful when using wildcard routes. you should put the **least specific** route in the **last place**, Lavarel will check all of specific routes. If it doesn't match, it will go to the wildcard route. For example :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/{profile_url?}',...); // Lavarel do this
    Route::get('/logout',...); // ignore this
}); 

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/logout',...); // do this if it matches
        Route::get('/{profile_url?}',...); // else do this
 });
```